# iOS Safari/WebKit current state of PWA persistence as of version 15.2

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, persistence, progressive-web-apps

I am reevaluating PWA feasibility for mostly offline based, occasionally used applications.
So far I had experience that PWAs on iOS does not have permanent storage as the website allocated space is often subject to cleanup either due to lack of space on a device or after N (I guess 7) days of application/website inactivity. I am aiming for fully installed PWA's (homepage).

According to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist) Safari should from version 15.2 fully implement the StorageManager persist API.
On the other hand I have not found such a statement in [Safari release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15_2-release-notes).

Can someone confirm or disconfirm the persistence of PWA's on iOS?

Without full persistence occasionally used offline ready PWA applications on iOS are no go zone. The only remaining alternative remains [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) then. Or other more exotic solutions then (like [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a definitive source, but this rather wordy article about PWA's on IOS says:

"There is a 50MB service worker cache limit, but that does not mean you cannot persist more data. IndexedDB allows you to store a few GBs of data. It really depends, like other platforms, on the available space.

There is no native add to homescreen prompt, but other than Chrome and Edge no one else does either.Unused web apps that have not been added to the homescreen will have their cached assets purged after 7 days. This is less of a problem than most think."

The key is "added to the home screen" for iOS Safari - per this.

But I don't see a definitive answer from Apple.

/https://love2dev.com/pwa/ios/